# unable to restore duplicity backup

Tags: duplicity

am unable to restore part of my duplicity backup, the file format is /media/ravi/TOSHIBA/Dejadup 090518/Part 2/duplicity-inc.20180507T183302Z.to.20180507T204510Z.vol1.difftar.gz. get a hash mismatch on trying to restore. kinldy help
ravi

Comment: Which version is this?

Answer (score 0):

a hash mismatch usually tells you that a volume got corrupted on the backend.

you can use the `--ignore-errors` parameter as documented in the [manpage](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/duplicity.1.html) to skip this error but probably all files that ended up in there will be unrestorable, check/save the console log to see which ones.

if your duplicity version still does not have the parameter, update to the latest duplicity 0.7.17 first. there are [ubuntu ppa's](https://launchpad.net/~duplicity-team/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) available.

..ede/duply.net